# Changing Rank Value in Excel Formula

Tags: excel

```
=RANK(F9,$F$5:$F$27,($A$43))
```

Can anyone help please. In the Rank formula above 'A43' refers to a cell whose value will constantly chnage between 1 and 22, depending on a time function. How do I tell the Rank formula to get the Rank Postion required from cell A43?

Comment: are you trying to pick a value from the range, rather than calculate the rank?

Answer (score 2):

though i don't exactly understand your question, here my approach to clarify what `RANK` exactly does:

```
=RANK(value, all_values, ordering)
```

whereas it returns the RANK of `value` out of the list of `all_values`. If `ordering` is 0, the function sorts descending, if 1 it sorts ascending.

you might consider [this example](http://excelhints.com/2007/06/15/rank-formula-in-excel/) for better understanding. It shows pretty well how to use the function.

the 3rd parameter of `RANK` (you provide the value of A43 here) is either 0 or 1 for descending or ascending ordering, respectively, and *not for the selection of the value you want the rank of.*

or am I getting you completely wrong?

regards

Comment: +1 NB any non-zero value for ordering results in a rank as if the list was sorted in ascending order

Comment: am i understanding you right? 0 = descending, anything else = ascending? regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the value of the cell in F5:F27 whose rank matches the value of A43.

Say you put the following in G5:

```
=RANK(F5,$F$5:$F$27)
```

and copied down to G27. Then this, (let's put it in G28):

```
=MATCH(A43,G5:G27,0)
```

will find the location of the specified rank in that list and

```
=INDEX(F5:F27,G28)
```

will give us the value.

If you're comfortable with [Array Formulae](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Excel+Array+Formulae) then this can be condensed into one super formula:

```
{=INDEX(F5:F27,MATCH(A43,RANK(F5:F27,F5:F27),0))}
```

(use the above without the braces and put it into the worksheet with Control-Shift-Enter)